# Download multiple files S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I wonder if there is a way to download (Rest or SDK) for multiple files (one bucket or a folder) in zip format (or other compression format).

Comment: No, you can't. Currently, AWS doesn't have download all object in a bucket. But, if you want, you can download all files into your local storage and create the compress file. AWS CLI also provide [sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) to download all object in a bucket into your local storage.

Answer (score 5):

As Edward pointed out in the comment, there is no straight forward way how to download these files in a compressed format from S3.

I was solving a similar issue to yours lately and I ended up with a bash script doing this job for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 sync s3://bucket1 /destination/bucket1
aws s3 sync s3://bucket2 /destination/bucket2
...
tar -zcvf bucket1.tar.gz /destination/bucket1
tar -zcvf bucket2.tar.gz /destination/bucket2
...
```

The workflow is as follows:

1. [Install the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)
2. [Setup the AWS credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)
3. Execute the script

You can use the appropriate commands to obtain the desired compression format and destinations etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to download mutiples files:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<your bucket name> . --recursive
```